# generate azure ad jwt token and call the thrid party api using those token using spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, azure-active-directory

I registered the app in an azure ad, and I have application id(client id) and directory id (tenant id), and secret key.

using this need to generate the jwt token in the azure ad and need to validate that token.

once the token generate need to call the third-party API's using that token in spring boot application.

please provide some example

Comment: Please refer the section of  How to configure Spring Security to work with JWT : https://www.bezkoder.com/spring-boot-jwt-authentication/

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the above requirement. You can take Reference of this [Post](https://www.bezkoder.com/spring-boot-jwt-authentication/) to call the third-party Api using the JWT token using spring boot application.

> In the above, there is [tutorial](https://www.bezkoder.com/spring-boot-jwt-authentication/#:%7E:text=project%20dependency%20&%20datasource.-,Spring%20Boot%20Signup%20&%20Login%20with%20JWT%20Authentication%20Flow,-The%20diagram%20shows) they have built a Spring Boot Application that supports Token based Authentication with JWT.  Please refer the section How to configure Spring Security to work with JWT that might be solution of requirement.